What is exactly pandas nan?
nan_value = pd.DataFrame(index = np.arange(10), columns = np.arange(10)).iloc[0,0]
nan_value == None, nan_value == np.nan, nan_value == pd.NA

(False, False, <NA>)

nan from pandas is not exactly equal to np.nan, None, or pd.NA
type(nan) also tells me it's float
What is nan from pandas??

Have you tried nan_value == nan_value?

@Koterpillar so it always return False?

Read the docs, e.g. 10 minutes to pandas § Missing data: "For NumPy data types, np.nan represents missing data." You can confirm that with nan_value is np.nan → True. Then under Missing data it covers equality comparisons (though they have a typo, *compaisons).

Nan means something that is missing, and you can't compare something that is missing to something else that is missing. I have this unknown thing. Is it equal to this other unknown thing? wouldn't make sense.
